# How to set a Windows folder's permissions using SID's in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-7

Just now I'm looking at fixing a localization bug with a small application that get's fired during the install of a software package.  The small application essentially brute forces permissions on our own folder within Application Data to set EVERYONE to full access.

The problem arises with EVERYONE not being localized.  I know I need to use SID's, which for EVERYONE, is `S-1-1-0`.  I can't find a WinAPI function for setting permissions using an SID.

The function just now uses `BuildExplicitAccessWithName` and `SetNamedSecurityInfo` as shown below

```
function setfullaccess(foldername:string):boolean;    //B2415 MDE
var
 pDACL: PACL;
 pEA: PEXPLICIT_ACCESS_A;
 R: DWORD;
begin
 result := true;
 pEA := AllocMem(SizeOf(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
 BuildExplicitAccessWithName(pEA, 'EVERYONE', GENERIC_ALL{GENERIC_READ},GRANT_ACCESS, SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT{NO_INHERITANCE});
 R := SetEntriesInAcl(1, pEA, nil, pDACL);
 if R = ERROR_SUCCESS then
 begin
  if SetNamedSecurityInfo(pchar(foldername), SE_FILE_OBJECT,DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, pDACL, nil) <> ERROR_SUCCESS then result := false;
  LocalFree(Cardinal(pDACL));
 end
 else result := false;//ShowMessage('SetEntriesInAcl failed: ' + SysErrorMessage(R));
end;
```

Which functions should I be looking at using instead?

Comment: Can't you just replace `'EVERYONE'` with `'S-1-1-0'`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me on my Windows 7 box.  Testing it using command line arguments for the folder name, using C:\TEMP.  When I use `S-1-1-0` there's no change, but using the end user readable version it successfully sets permissions.

When running with the debugger attached I'm looking at my variable R which is the error code attached to `SetEntriesInAcl`.  It returns 1332 : No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching through the WinAPI documentation I went for the solution below.  Essentially I use the SID to lookup the "readable" name and then use that.  It won't be the most elegant solution but it works for me.

```
procedure TTestform.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 Sid: PSID;
 peUse: DWORD;
 cchDomain: DWORD;
 cchName: DWORD;
 Name: array of Char;
 Domain: array of Char;
 pDACL: PACL;
 pEA: PEXPLICIT_ACCESS_A;
 R: DWORD;
 foldername: String; //Temp to hardcode
begin
 foldername := 'C:\TEMP'; //Temp to hardcode
 Sid := nil;
 Win32Check(ConvertStringSidToSidA(PChar('S-1-1-0'), Sid));
 cchName := 0;
 cchDomain := 0;
 //Get Length
 if (not LookupAccountSid(nil, Sid, nil, cchName, nil, cchDomain, peUse)) and (GetLastError = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) then
 begin
  SetLength(Name, cchName);
  SetLength(Domain, cchDomain);
  if LookupAccountSid(nil, Sid, @Name[0], cchName, @Domain[0], cchDomain, peUse) then
  begin
   pEA := AllocMem(SizeOf(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
   BuildExplicitAccessWithName(pEA, PChar(Name), GENERIC_ALL{GENERIC_READ},GRANT_ACCESS, SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT{NO_INHERITANCE});
   R := SetEntriesInAcl(1, pEA, nil, pDACL);
   if R = ERROR_SUCCESS then
   begin
    if SetNamedSecurityInfo(pchar(foldername), SE_FILE_OBJECT,DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, pDACL, nil) <> ERROR_SUCCESS then ShowMessage('SetNamedSecurityInfo failed: ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
    LocalFree(Cardinal(pDACL));
   end
   else ShowMessage('SetEntriesInAcl failed: ' + SysErrorMessage(R));
  end;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: The following MSDN article shows how to retrieve the SID of the Everyone group and use it with `SetEntriesInAcl()` without having to resort to `ConvertStringSidToSid()` or `LookupAccountSid()` to convert the SID to a name string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446595(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach to avoid using both `lookup` and `build`

```
var SID: JwaWinNT.PSid; // JWA clashes with Delphi XE2 Windows.Windows.PSID type
    pDACL: PACL;
    EA: EXPLICIT_ACCESS;
    SID_DATA: array[1..SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE] of byte;
    SID_DATA_SIZE: DWORD;

   SID_DATA_SIZE := Length(SID_DATA);
   Pointer(SID) := @SID_DATA; // @SID_DATA[Low(SID_DATA)]  for non-static arrays 

    pDACL := nil;
//   if ConvertStringSidToSid(Auth_Users_SID, SID) then
   if CreateWellKnownSid(WinAuthenticatedUserSid, nil, SID, SID_DATA_SIZE) then
   try
      EA.grfInheritance := SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT; // NO_INHERITANCE; // 0
      EA.grfAccessMode :=  GRANT_ACCESS;
      EA.grfAccessPermissions := GENERIC_ALL;

      EA.Trustee.MultipleTrusteeOperation := NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE;
      EA.Trustee.pMultipleTrustee := nil;
      EA.Trustee.TrusteeType := TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
      EA.Trustee.TrusteeForm := TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
      EA.Trustee.ptstrName   := pointer(SID); 

      if ERROR_SUCCESS = SetEntriesInAcl(1, @EA, nil, pDACL) then begin

       // optional creation of PATH and 0-bytes dummy file skipped 

        SetNamedSecurityInfo(pchar(foldername), SE_FILE_OBJECT, ....  {see the author's answer above }
      end;

   finally
     LocalFree(pDACL); // SID is not allocated on heap - no need to free it
   end;
```

This snippet can also be checked against the unit at page #2 at http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-374131/0.html#st_15_view_0